# $\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K} \subset \mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$ implies $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a noetherian $K$ algebra, that is a noetherian ring with $K$-module
structure. Let $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b} \subset R$ two ideals and $\overline{K}$ the algebraic
closure of $K$. Assume $\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K} \subset
\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$.

Is it possible to show that $\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K} \subset
\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$ implies $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{b}$ only with methods from elementary
linear algebra (that is using only theory of vector spaces, bases, etc.) ?
Can the argument be generalized to the case when we consider an arbitrary field
extension $K \subset L$ instead of $K \subset \overline{K}$?

my tryings: the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is a $K$-vector space and let $B_{\mathfrak{a}}:=\{a_1, a_2,... \}$ it's $K$-basis. Because $R$ neotherian, $B_{\mathfrak{a}}$ is countable. Then
$B_{\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K}}:=
\{a_1 \otimes 1_{\overline{K}}, a_2 \otimes 1_{\overline{K}},
... \}$ is a $\overline{K}$-basis of $\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K}$, which is contaned
in $\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$. Let $B_{\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}}:=
\{\overline{b_1}, \overline{b_2},... \}$ be a $\overline{K}$-basis of
$\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$.

Can I extract a basis $B_{\mathfrak{b}}$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ which contains $B_{\mathfrak{a}}$ only with linear algbera methods? If I can't do it a priori, can I use another abstract argument
to show $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{b}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for an arbitrary extension $L \supset K$, not only the algebraic closure. You thus have $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}) \otimes L=\mathfrak{b} \otimes L$.

So, $\left((\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})/\mathfrak{b}\right) \otimes L=0$. By taking a $K$-basis of $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})/\mathfrak{b}$ it follows that $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})/\mathfrak{b}=0$, so that $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b} \supset \mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: by the way can we also prove it with basis suplementation theorem as follows? 
Since $B_{\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K}} \subset 
\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$ then we can build a "special" basis
$B$ of $\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$ which contains 
$B_{\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K}}$. Recall  
$B_{\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K \overline{K}}$ consists of vectors
$a_i \otimes 1$. These live in subring $\mathfrak{b} \otimes 1 \subset 
\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K \overline{K}$. But $\mathfrak{b} \otimes 1$ is canonically
isomorphic to $B$ as $K$-space.

Comment: Therefore $a_i \otimes 1 \subset
\mathfrak{b} \otimes 1$. Is this "proof" also correct?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent convinced, you need to be pretty careful, because it's not because $"a_i \otimes 1" \in \mathfrak{b} \otimes \overline{K}$ that it can be represented by some $\beta \otimes 1$. It makes sense if you see all your elements and sets as subspaces of a canonical total, e.g. $R \otimes \overline{K}$.

Comment: I would like to correct my argument using your
hint to regard all inclusions in a 'total space'.
Could you check if it is correct now?

Comment: Let work with arbitrary finite extension $L \supset K$ 
instead $\overline{K}$ and assume we have inclusion
$\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K L \subset
\mathfrak{b} \otimes_K L$. As you suggested
we regard this as an inclusion of subspaces
of $R \otimes_K L$, where $\mathfrak{a}, 
\mathfrak{b}$ & $R$ are naturally contained
in $R \otimes_K L$
via $r \mapsto r \otimes 1_L$.

Comment: We have only to show that
$(\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K L) \cap (R \otimes 1_L)=
\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K 1_L \cong \mathfrak{a}$
as subsets in $R \otimes_K L$.  
"$\supset$" is clear. For "$\subset$" we 
observe that we can regard
$R \otimes_K L$ as free $R$-module with free
$R$-basis $1_R \otimes 1_K, 1_R \otimes k_1,...
1_R \otimes k_n$, where $1_K, k_1,... k_n$ is
$K$-basis of $L$. Then an element from
$(\mathfrak{a} \otimes_K L) \cap (R \otimes 1_L)$
equals $r \otimes 1_K =
b_0 \otimes 1_K + b_1 \otimes k_1 + ...
+ b_n \otimes k_n$.

Comment: Comparison of coeffients gives
$b_0= r$ and $b_i=0$ for $i \neq 0$. So the punshline seems to be to reinterpret the inclusion as a inclusion contained in free $R$-module $R \otimes L \cong R^n$ and to use $R$-coeffcient comparison.  Is this 
argument correct now or is there still a gap?